# Executing Error in python

Tags: python

```
import unittest

service = ('u', 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:service:SwitchPower:1')
binary_light_type = 'urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:BinaryLight:1'

def on_new_device(dev):
    """ Callback triggered when a new device is found.
    """
    print 'Got new device:', dev.udn
    print "Type 'list' to see the whole list"

    if not dev:
        return

def get_switch_service(device):
    return device.services[service[1]]

def create_control_point():
    """ Creates the control point and binds callbacks to device events.
    """
    c = ControlPoint()
    c.subscribe('new_device_event', on_new_device)
    c.subscribe('removed_device_event', on_removed_device)
    return c

def main():
    """ Main loop iteration receiving input commands.
    """
    c = create_control_point()
    c.start()
    run_async_function(_handle_cmds, (c, ))
    reactor.add_after_stop_func(c.stop)
    reactor.main()


def _exit(c):
    """ Stops the _handle_cmds loop
    """
    global running_handle_cmds
    running_handle_cmds = False

def _search(c):
    """ Start searching for devices of type upnp:rootdevice and repeat
    search every 600 seconds (UPnP default)
    """
    c.start_search(600, 'upnp:rootdevice')

def _get_status(c):
    """ Gets the binary light status and print if it's on or off.
    """
    try:
        service = get_switch_service(c.current_server)
        status_response = service.GetStatus()
        if status_response['ResultStatus'] == '1':
            print 'Binary light status is on'
        else:
            print 'Binary light status is off'
    except Exception, e:
        if not hasattr(c, 'current_server') or not c.current_server:
            print 'BinaryLight device not set.Please use set_light <n>'
        else:
            print 'Error in get_status():', e

def _get_target(c):
    """ Gets the binary light target and print if it's on or off.
    """
    try:
        service = get_switch_service(c.current_server)
        status_response = service.GetTarget()
        if status_response['RetTargetValue'] == '1':
            print 'Binary light target is on'
        else:
            print 'Binary light target is off'
    except Exception, e:
        if not hasattr(c, 'current_server') or not c.current_server:
            print 'BinaryLight device not set.Please use set_light <n>'
        else:
            print 'Error in get_target():', e
def _stop(c):
    """ Stop searching
    """
    c.stop_search()

def _list_devices(c):
    """ Lists the devices that are in network.
    """
    k = 0
    for d in c.get_devices().values():
        print 'Device no.:', k
        print 'UDN:', d.udn
        print 'Name:', d.friendly_name
        print 'Device type:', d.device_type
        print 'Services:', d.services.keys() # Only print services name
        print 'Embedded devices:', [dev.friendly_name for dev in \
             d.devices.values()] # Only print embedded devices names
        print
        k += 1

running_handle_cmds = True
commands = {'exit': _exit, 

            'search': _search,
            'stop': _stop,
            'list': _list_devices,


            'get_status': _get_status,
            'get_target': _get_target}


def _handle_cmds(c):
    while running_handle_cmds:
        try:
            input = raw_input('>>> ').strip()
            if len(input.split(" ")) > 0:
                try:
                    if len(input.split(" ")) > 1:
                        commands[input.split(" ")[0]](c, input.split(" ")[1])
                    else:
                        commands[input.split(" ")[0]](c)
                except KeyError, IndexError:
                    print 'Invalid command, try help'
                except TypeError:
                    print 'Wrong usage, try help to see'
        except KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError:
            c.stop()
            break

    # Stops the main loop
    reactor.main_quit()

# Here's our "unit tests".
class IsOddTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def testOne(self):
        self.failUnless(_search(c))

    def testTwo(self):
        self.failIf(_search(upnp:rootdevice))

def main():
    unittest.main()
```

When I try to run this file , it throws me 2 errors:The above code is wriiten for test cases.

```
======================================================================
ERROR: testOne (__main__.IsOddTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controlpt.py", line 145, in testOne
    self.failUnless(_get_status(c))
NameError: global name 'c' is not defined

======================================================================
ERROR: testTwo (__main__.IsOddTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "controlpt.py", line 148, in testTwo
    self.failIf(_search(0))
  File "controlpt.py", line 55, in _search
    c.start_search(600, 'upnp:rootdevice')
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'start_search'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is simple: call it with something that *is* defined.

The second one is also simple: call it with an object that has a `start_search` attribute.

Beyond that we don't know. You haven't explained what any of this code is and what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I only have used this code. Where should I define for the first test ?case

Comment: so, what it should be?? I mean?? I am using only this file and executing it with python controlpt.py...where should I make change??

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like you should hand this project over to someone who knows elementary Python programming.